# Stubbing s3 in pytest with FastAPI throws AttributeError

Tags: mocking, boto3, fastapi

I'm trying to stub s3 for testing the image upload endpoint of a fastapi toy project

My test:

```
class TestAPI:
    client = TestClient(app)
    s3 = botocore.session.get_session().create_client('s3')

    def test_can_upload_image(self):
        s3_put_object_params = {
            'Bucket': 'my-bucket',
            'Key': 'image.jpg',
            'Body': ANY
        }

        s3_put_object_acl_params = {
            'Bucket': 'my-bucket',
            'Key': 'image.jpg',
            'ACL': 'public-read'
        }

        with Stubber(s3) as stubber:
            stubber.add_response('put_object', {}, expected_params=s3_put_object_params)
            stubber.add_response('put_object_acl', {}, expected_params=s3_put_object_acl_params)
            stubber.activate()

            response = self.client.post('image/upload', files={'file': open('image.jpg', 'rb')})

        assert response is True
```

and the endpoint code:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3_bucket = 'my-bucket'

@app.post('/image/upload')
async def upload_image(file: UploadFile, generate_random_filename=True):
    if not is_image_extension(file.filename):
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail='Invalid file extension. Only images allowed.')

    contents = await file.read()
    sanitized_filename = generate_filename(file.filename) if generate_random_filename else file.filename

    s3.Bucket(s3_bucket).put_object(Key=sanitized_filename, Body=contents)
    s3.ObjectAcl(s3_bucket, sanitized_filename).put(ACL='public-read')

    data = {
        'filename': file.filename,
        's3_object_key': sanitized_filename
    }

    return True
```

the error that I'm getting is:

```
test_main.py::TestAPI::test_can_upload_image FAILED                      [100%]
test_main.py:11 (TestAPI.test_can_upload_image)
self = <test_main.TestAPI object at 0x10ebcf6d0>

    def test_can_upload_image(self):
        s3_put_object_params = {
            'Bucket': 'my-bucket',
            'Key': 'image.jpg',
            'Body': ANY
        }
    
        s3_put_object_acl_params = {
            'Bucket': 'my-bucket',
            'Key': 'image.jpg',
            'ACL': 'public-read'
        }
    
>       with Stubber(s3) as stubber:

test_main.py:25: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/stub.py:177: in __enter__
    self.activate()
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = <botocore.stub.Stubber object at 0x10ebec250>

    def activate(self):
        """
        Activates the stubber on the client
        """
>       self.client.meta.events.register_first(
            'before-parameter-build.*.*',
            self._assert_expected_params,
            unique_id=self._expected_params_event_id)
E       AttributeError: 'ResourceMeta' object has no attribute 'events'

venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/stub.py:187: AttributeError
```

Could someone shine a light to where am I doing wrong, please?